# Selecting Data With MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small challenge to solve in a query, I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total, products, DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, '%M') AS month
FROM orders
WHERE Status = 'paid'
AND YEAR(TransDate) = '2016'
GROUP BY Product, YEAR(TransDate), MONTH(TransDate)
ORDER BY TransDate ASC
```

My return on this query is this:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <th>total</th>
  <th>Product</th>
  <th>Month</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>12000</td>
  <td>Ford Mondeo</td>
  <td>Jan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>23000</td>
  <td>Camaro</td>
  <td>Jan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>9000</td>
  <td>Golf</td>
  <td>Jan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>42000</td>
  <td>Audi A4</td>
  <td>Jan</td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>4566</td>
  <td>Ford Mondeo</td>
  <td>Feb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>35435</td>
  <td>Camaro</td>
  <td>Feb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>58456</td>
  <td>Golf</td>
  <td>Feb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>56465</td>
  <td>Audi A4</td>
  <td>Feb</td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>3522</td>
  <td>Ford Mondeo</td>
  <td>Mar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>468132</td>
  <td>Camaro</td>
  <td>Mar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>25225</td>
  <td>Golf</td>
  <td>Mar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>54612</td>
  <td>Audi A4</td>
  <td>Mar</td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>12000</td>
  <td>Ford Mondeo</td>
  <td>Apr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>23000</td>
  <td>Camaro</td>
  <td>Apr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>9000</td>
  <td>Golf</td>
  <td>Apr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>42000</td>
  <td>Audi A4</td>
  <td>Apr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>54554</td>
  <td>Beatle</td>
  <td>Apr</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>12000</td>
  <td>Ford Mondeo</td>
  <td>May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>23000</td>
  <td>Camaro</td>
  <td>May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>9000</td>
  <td>Golf</td>
  <td>May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>42000</td>
  <td>Audi A4</td>
  <td>May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>54554</td>
  <td>Beatle</td>
  <td>May</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What happens in my case is that the beatle car has only sales values in the last two months and in the previous months no, I would like to know if there is any way of it appearing in other months with the total value of 0, and in the months that the car actually had sale its full value is correct.

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2):

Use a `cross join` to generate all the product/date combinations.  Then use `left join` to bring in the orders info.  You can get the dates using a subquery on `orders`, if you don't have another handy method (say a calendar table):

```
SELECT ym.yyyymm, p.product, COALESCE(SUM(o.total), 0) AS total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, '%M') as yyyymm,
             YEAR(TransDate) as yyyy, MONTH(TransDate) as mm
      FROM orders o
      WHERE TransDate >= '2016-01-01' and TransDate < '2017-01-01'
     ) ym CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT o.product FROM orders o
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON YEAR(o.TransDate) = ym.yyyy AND
        MONTH(o.TransDate) = ym.mm AND
        o.product = p.product AND
        o.Status = 'paid'
GROUP BY p.Product, ym.yyyymm
ORDER BY MIN(o.TransDate), p.Product;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the answer.
But, if I already have a left join in this query how would the change be?
for example:

SELECT SUM(Amount) AS total, orders.products, DATE_FORMAT(TransDate, '%M') AS month
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.ordnumber = transactions.ordnumber
WHERE (transactions.Status IS NULL OR transactions.Status = 'paid')
AND YEAR(transactions.TransDate) = '2016'
GROUP BY orders.Product, YEAR(transactions.TransDate), MONTH(transactions.TransDate)
ORDER BY transactions.TransDate ASC

Comment: @Vitor . . . You just use `left join`s to bring in the additional tables. If that is not sufficient, you should ask *another* question.  This question clearly references only one table and this answers the question that you have asked.

Comment: Yes it answers the question clearly, so I thanked you